# Is a train in J associative

Tags: j, apl, tacit-programming

In programming language J, is a train of verbs always associative?  If it is, Are there any proofs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, a train of verbs is not associative and this follows the definitions. For example, a fork is

```
(f g h) y = (f y) g (h y)
```

but

```
(f (g h)) y = y f ((g h) y) = y f (y g (h y))
```

which can also be written as `y f y g h y`. And

```
((f g) h) y = y (f g) (h y) = y f (g (h y))
```

which can also be written as `y f g h y`.

Those three are completely different things.

Answer (score 1):

Train in J is `right associative`, and the minimum group is a `fork`. Only when it cannot make a fork, it makes a hook. So

```
vvvvv = (vv(vvv)),
```

And

```
vvvv= (v(vvv)).
```